# Que un Combobox memorice el valor previo

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, estoy por primera vez usando combobox en un formulario de Laravel.

Tengo este modelo:

```
    Schema::create('fotos', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->string('nombre')->unique();
        $table->date('fecha');
        $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id'); // Forarea de Categoria.
        $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); // Foranea de User.
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Para lo que me interesa cogemos la variable `categoria_id`, que es foraneo de otra tabla llamada Categoria.

Tengo este fragmento de código:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="categoria_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Categoría de la foto</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select name="categoria_id" class="form-control">
            @foreach($categorias as $categoria) 
            <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}">{{$categoria->nombre}}</option> 
            @endforeach
        </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

El cual me da esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El combobox funciona, pero imaginemos que estoy intentando modificar una foto ya existente. Quiero que el formulario muestre cual es el valor actual de la foto. ¿Como logro eso?

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo yo mismo.
Este es el código:

```
@foreach($categorias as $categoria) 
    <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}" {{$f->categoria_id==$categoria->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$categoria->nombre}}</option> 
@endforeach
```

Siendo `$f` la foto que quiero modificar.